# How draw diagram with Markdown

Tags: c#, markdown

I use [Markdig](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig) to render the Markdown text. I saw it is possible to draw same diagrams.

So, I wrote this code

```
var pipeline = new MarkdownPipelineBuilder().UseAdvancedExtensions().Build();
ValueHTML = Markdig.Markdown.ToHtml(value ?? string.Empty, pipeline);
```

Some functionalities are working, for example Markdig renders the table but not the diagrams.

[image]

What do I have to do?

Comment: Were you able to get this working with the answer shown below?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't look like Mermaid is built *into* Markdig. Rather, Markdig [leaves the source unmodified](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig#features), just as you are seeing:

> [Diagrams](https://github.com/xoofx/markdig/blob/master/src/Markdig.Tests/Specs/DiagramsSpecs.md) extension whenever a fenced code block contains a special keyword, it will be converted to a div block with the content as-is (currently, supports [`mermaid`](https://knsv.github.io/mermaid/) and [`nomnoml`](https://github.com/skanaar/nomnoml) diagrams)

Normally, code blocks are rendered using `<pre>` and `<code>`. Leaving the content in a ```` ```mermaid ```` block unmodified should allow Mermaid to render it. Note that this doesn't say anything about actually rendering the diagram.

I suspect you'll have to add Mermaid yourself, e.g. by following [the "Calling the Javascript API" example](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/n00b-gettingStarted?id=_3-calling-the-javascript-api):

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mermaid/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>

<script>
  mermaid.initialize({ startOnLoad: true });
</script>
```

(I *think* Markdig will add the required `mermaid` class to the relevant div for you, but it's hard to tell.)

Comment: See also - https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/README?id=deploying-mermaid. This confirms that mermaid is running in the browser after MarkDig has output the appropriate HTML - `<div class="mermaid"></div>`